# Google Sheets date calculation

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to take a date in one row and auto calculate another date in another column 10 days out?

ex: (column a) 12/11/20 -auto calculate the date 10 days from then
and put in (column d) 12/21/20.

So anytime I enter a date and need the 10 day out date it just auto calculates so I don't have to keep entering the date over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using **`ARRAYFORMULA()`**.

> **ARRAYFORMULA** enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays.

Try this: `=Arrayformula(TO_DATE(IF(A1:A="","", A1:A+10)))`.

Example:

[image]

### Reference

[Arrayformula()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)